# Should I use OEM recovery media software or Windows 10 build-in?

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup

The question is pretty much in the title. I've got various PCs around the house that are from different manufacturers (Acer, Toshiba, and a Custom-built rig), all upgraded to Windows 10. I once had a problem laptop (belonging to a friend), where they hadn't created any recovery media, needed it reinstalling and the Windows key in the BIOS wouldn't activate. After that, I started making recovery media for all of my PCs, but I noticed that I've got the option of using either the OEM's recovery media creation software or the windows built-in tool. Which one should I use to make sure that I can restore and have everything activate successfully? I've also made note of my product keys using ProduKey.

Comment: Windows. Surely you would like to use it for more than one manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

OEM recovery media will recover it to the factory software and original OS, its not a bad idea to make this media and store it.

Use the Windows tool to make recovery media also, use this to recover quickly rather than reinstalling the original OS and have to upgrade to W10 again.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best solution would be a usb or cd/dvd with the Windows installation disk. There is a built-in system recovery. But you should always make a backup (I learned the hard way 3 days ago. I just deleted my old backup and I was going to make a new one 2 days later)